# Spark Scala custom UnaryTransformer in a pipeline fails on read of persisted pipeline model

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have developed this simple LogTransformer by extending the UnaryTransformer to apply log transfromation on the "age" column in the DataFrame. I am able to apply this transformer and include that as a pipeline stage and persist the pipeline model after training.

```
class LogTransformer(override val uid: String) extends UnaryTransformer[Int, 
Double, LogTransformer] with DefaultParamsWritable {

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("logTransformer"))

  override protected def createTransformFunc: Int => Double = (feature: Int) => {Math.log10(feature)}

  override protected def validateInputType(inputType: DataType): Unit = {
    require(inputType == DataTypes.IntegerType, s"Input type must be integer type but got $inputType.")
  }

  override protected def outputDataType: DataType = DataTypes.DoubleType

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): LogTransformer = defaultCopy(extra)
}

object LogTransformer extends DefaultParamsReadable[LogTransformer]
```

But when I read the persisted model I get the following exception.

```
val MODEL_PATH = "model/census_pipeline_model"

cvModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel].write.overwrite.save(MODEL_PATH)

val same_pipeline_model = PipelineModel.load(MODEL_PATH)

exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: dsml.Census$LogTransformer$2.read()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.loadParamsInstance(ReadWrite.scala:652)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$$anonfun$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:274)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$$anonfun$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:272)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$.load(Pipeline.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:348)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:342)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable$class.load(ReadWrite.scala:380)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$.load(Pipeline.scala:332)
at dsml.Census$.main(Census.scala:572)
at dsml.Census.main(Census.scala)
```

Any pointers on how to fix that would be helpful. Thank You.